# NSCollectionView not updating when adding objects

Tags: cocoa, key-value-coding, nscollectionview

I have an NSCollectionView with an array controller that is successfully showing objects after they are added and the application is restarted, but not when immediately when added.

I have a controller class which is a subclass of NSObject that reads data from a plist into an NSMutableArray, which is bound to an Array Controller, which is in turn bound to my NSCollectionView. I believe my bindings are correct, as if I add an object, after I restart my application, everything shows up fine, including the new object and all the bound attributes. But when I add an object, it won't be added immediately. The application needs to be restarted. I believe that since my bindings appear to be correct, this is an issue with my controller class not being Key-Value compliant.

I have implemented all of the methods I believe I should have, as per the "Key-Value Coding Accessor Methods" section of the Key-Value Coding programming guide. I believe I have implemented each of the required accessors in the [Collection Accessor Patterns for To-Many Properties][1] section. Furthermore, in the [Quick Start for Collection Views][2], which I have completed, it states not even all of these methods need to be implemented (which I have confirmed).

Here are some code samples to better explain what I am doing.

My collection class, "MYCollection":

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyObject.h"

@interface MYCollection : NSObject
@property (retain, readwrite) NSMutableArray* objects;
- (void)insertObject:(MYObject *)object inObjectsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

#import "MYObjectCollection.h"
#import "MYObject.h"

@implementation MYObjectCollection

@synthesize objects = _objects;

- (id)init {

  self = [super init]; 
  if (self) {
    _objects = [self objects];
  }

  return self;
}

- (NSArray*)objects {

  // here I retrieve the objects from the plist into a mutable array
  // let's call that array "sortedArray"

  return sortedArray;
}

- (void)setObjects:(NSMutableArray *)objectsArray {

  // here I write the object array to a plist

  _objects = objectsArray;
}

-(void)insertObject:(MYObject*)object inObjectsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

  [_objects insertObject:object atIndex:index];
  [self setObjects:_objects];
  return;
}

-(void)addObjectsObject:(MYObject*)object {

  [_objects addObject:object];
  [self setObjects:_objects];
  return;
}

-(void)removeObjectFromObjectsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

  [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:index];
  [self setObjects:_objects];
  return;
}

-(void)removeObjectsObject:(MYObject*)object {

  [_objects removeObject:object];
  [self setObjects:_objects];
  return;
}

-(id)objectInObjectsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

  return [_objects objectAtIndex:index];
}

-(NSUInteger)countOfObjects {

  return [_objects count];
}

- (NSEnumerator *)enumeratorOfObjects {

  return [_objects objectEnumerator];
}

@end
```

I am adding objects to this controller by means of an external view, elsewhere:

```
MYObjectCollection *collection = [[MYObjectCollection alloc] init];
[collection insertObject:new inObjectsAtIndex:[collection.objects count]];
```

I'm not sure how to continue troubleshooting this issue. I believe that my bindings are correct and I think I have implemented all of the necessary methods for Key-Value coding, but maybe I haven't, or maybe they're wrong. Any help would be appreciated.